# Strong name verification failed for the instrumented assembly - Ninject

Tags: ninject

We've just started using Ninject in a Visual Studio project. 
When I run the tests with Code Coverage enabled I get the error below:

> Strong name verification failed for the instrumented assembly 'Ninject, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7'. Please ensure that the right key file for re-signing after instrumentation is specified in the test settings.

In *Test > Edit Test Settings > Local > Data and Diagnostics > Code Coverage*

It is enabled.

I've selected the dll's which I wish to cover.

We've set re-signing to the strong key that we're using for the project.

However I'm still getting the error

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. 
I downloaded the ninject source code. 
Deleted their key and added ours. 
Rebuilt it.